# Insert statement not working using execute(array()) of PDO Extension

Tags: pdo, php

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('',:username,md5(:password),'',1,'','',:email,'',0,0,'',:cover,:dateofbirthYear:dateofbirthMonth:dateofbirthDay,NOW(),:sex,:country)");
 $stmt->execute(array(
  ':username'   => $username,
  ':password' => $password,
  ':email'   => $email,
  ':cover' => $cover,
  ':dateofbirthYear'   => $dateofbirthYear,
  ':dateofbirthMonth' => $dateofbirthMonth,
  ':dateofbirthDay'   => $dateofbirthDay,
  ':sex' => $sex,
  ':country'   => $country 
    ));
```

For some reason this insert statement is not working. I am very new in PDO so I do not know much about it. What am I doing wrong?

this statment gives me this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /home/manga/public_html/new/register.php:80 Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/manga/public_html/new/register.php(80): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>   #1 {main} thrown in /home/manga/public_html/new/register.php on line 80

Comment: "I have looked up the error on stackoverflow" And have you tried thinking about it for yourself?

Comment: @feeela If I did not, why would I put the question in here?

Comment: You really should [not be using `md5`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) to [hash passwords](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have prepared your query in the wrong way

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES ('',:username,md5(:password),'',1,'','',:email,'',0,0,'',
:cover,:dateofbirthYear:dateofbirthMonth:dateofbirthDay,NOW(),:sex,:country
     // ^ These need to either single or separated
```

For what you are trying, you can do it this way

```
//Prepare the date of birth earlier
$dob = $dateofbirthYear.$dateofbirthMonth.$dateofbirthDay;

//Then pass it as a single $variable

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('',:username,md5(:password),'',1,'','',:email,'',0,0,'',:cover,:dob,NOW(),:sex,:country)");
 $stmt->execute(array(
  ':username'   => $username,
  ':password' => $password,
  ':email'   => $email,
  ':cover' => $cover,
  ':dob'   => $dob, // <-- Problem solved
  ':sex' => $sex,
  ':country'   => $country 
    ));
 // Then it will execute
```

Comment: I cannot believe that this was the error! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The exact error message you have is:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

This means that the number/names of parameters you have passed (the `array()` in `execute`) does not match with the number/names of parameters you have in the `prepare()` SQL-query.

If you [compare that with the other questions that contain *`SQLSTATE[HY093]`*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpdo%5D+%22SQLSTATE%5BHY093%5D%22) you will see that it is often related to code that is large and bad formatted which is hard to read. That makes it hard to count. And then you have an oversight of something and then the error happened.

Just fix it and done, for example you can not make one parameter out of three names:

```
,:dateofbirthYear:dateofbirthMonth:dateofbirthDay,
```

Instead just pass one parameter for the birthday:

```
, :dateofbirth,
```

You can also make your code a bit more readable:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO user
     VALUES (
        '', :username, md5(:password), '', 1, '', '', :email, '', 0, 0, '',
        :cover, :dateofbirth, NOW(), :sex, :country
     )"
);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':username'    => $username,
    ':password'    => $password,
    ':email'       => $email,
    ':cover'       => $cover,
    ':dateofbirth' => $dateofbirthYear . $dateofbirthMonth . $dateofbirthDay,
    ':sex'         => $sex,
    ':country'     => $country
));
```

And then you have a security problem with the password hash:

```
md5(:password)
```

Instead do proper password hashing, see the [PHP FAQ about Safe Password Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't like the fact that you just made my answer obsolete with that edit :(

Comment: How can I make you smile again?

Comment: That was the least expected response. :) (retracting my vote)

Comment: your answer is similar to @Starx answer. I have picked his as the right answer because he answered it first. But thank you for the clarification. I will take a look of that Password Hash thing.

Comment: yes check with the password hash, the FAQ explains what is wrong with `md5()`. We also have some good Q&A here on site about that that are going into more details.

Answer (score -2):

Corrected prepared query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('',:username,md5(:password),'',1,'','',:email,'',0,0,'',:cover,:dateofbirthYear,:dateofbirthMonth:,dateofbirthDay,NOW(),:sex,:country)");
//:dateofbirthYear,:dateofbirthMonth:,dateofbirthDay place holders are seprated 

$stmt->execute(array(
 ':username'   => $username,
  ':password' => $password,
  ':email'   => $email,
  ':cover' => $cover,
  ':dateofbirthYear'   => $dateofbirthYear,
  ':dateofbirthMonth' => $dateofbirthMonth,
  ':dateofbirthDay'   => $dateofbirthDay,
  ':sex' => $sex,
  ':country'   => $country 
));
```